# Hadoop: Sending Files or File paths to a map reduce job

Tags: file, hadoop, path, mapreduce, streaming

supposed I had N files to process using hadoop map-reduce, let's assume they are large, well beyond the block size and there are only a few hundred of them. Now I would like to process each of these files, let's assume the word counting example.

My question is: What is the difference between creating a map-reduce job whose input is a text file with the paths to each of the files as opposed to sending each of the files directly to the map function i.e. concatenating all the files and pushing **them into different mappers [EDIT]**.

Are these both valid approaches?
Are there any drawbacks to them?

**Thanks for the prompt answers I've included a detailed description of my problem since my abstraction may have missed a few important topics:**

I have N small files on Hadoop HDFS in my application and I just need to process each file. So I am using a map function to apply a python script to each file (actually image [I've already looked at all the hadoop image processing links out there]), I am aware of the small file problem and the typical recommendation is to group the smaller files so we avoid the overhead of moving files around (the basic recommendation using sequence files or creating your own data structures as in the case of the HIPI).

***This makes me wonder can't we just tell each mapper to look for files that are local to him and operate on those?***

I haven't found a solution to that issue which is why I was looking at either sending a path to the files to each mapper or the file it self.

Creating a list of path names for each of the collection of images seems to be ok, but as mentioned in the comments I loose the data locality property.

Now when I looked at the hadoop streaming interface it mentions that the different pieces communicate based on stdin and stdout typically used for text files. That's where I get confused, if I am just sending a list of path names this shouldn't be an issue since each mapper would just try to find the collection of images it is assigned. But when I look at the word count example the input is the file which then gets split up across the mappers and **so that's when I was confused as to if I should concatenate images into groups and then send these concatenated groups just like the text document to the different mappers or if I should instead concatenate the images leave them in hadoop HDFS and then just pass the path to them to the mapper**... I hope this makes sense... maybe I'm completely off here...

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are valid. But latter would incur extra overhead and performance will go down because you are  talking about concatenating all the files into one and feeding it to just 1 mapper. And by doing that you would go against one of the most basic principles of Hadoop, `parallelism`. Parallelism is what makes Hadoop so efficient.

FYI, if you really need to do that you have to set `isSplittable` to false in your `InputFormat` class, otherwise the framework will split the file(based on your InputFormat).

And as far as input path is considered, you just need to give the path of the input directory. Each file inside this directory will be processed without human intervention.

HTH

---

In response to your edit :

I think you have misunderstood this a bit. You don't have to worry about localization. Hadoop takes care of that. You just have to run your job and the data will be processed on the node where it is present. Size of the file has nothing to with it. You don't have to tell anything to mappers. Process goes like this :

You submit your job to JT. JT directs the TT running on the node which has the block of data required by the job to start start the mappers. If the slots are occupied by some other process, then same thing takes place on some other node having the data block.

Comment: I made a mistake I meant the difference between creating a map-reduce job whose input is a text file with the paths to each of the files as opposed to sending each of the files directly to the map function i.e. concatenating all the files and pushing them into different mappers [EDIT].

Comment: I see, so if the N files are stored in HDFS and are referenced either by a text file with all their paths stored per line or by providing the input directory to where they all reside hadoop MR will automatically take care of all the parallelization (I assume I just have to be careful with the inputformat). My confusion comes from the comment that others as well as Chris White made where they mention that by sending the paths one looses locality. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck will be there if you are processing the whole concatenated file in a single mapper as you have mentioned.

It won't be a problem is you are providing the concatenated file as input to Hadoop. Since, the large file formed will obviously be distributed in HDFS (I assume you are using HDFS) and will be processed by multiple Mappers and reducers concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: What is the difference between creating a map-reduce job whose input is a text file with the paths to each of the files as opposed to sending each of the files directly to the map function i.e. concatenating all the files and pushing them into a single mapper.

By listing the files paths in a text file and (i assume) manually opening them in the mapper, you'll be defeating data locality (that is where hadoop will try and run your mapper code where the data is, rather than moving the data to where your code executes. with 1000 files, this will also probably be processed by a single mapper instance (i imagine 1000 lines of text should be less than your block size).

If you concatenate all the files first and then use as input, this will usually be less efficient, mainly because you're copying all the files to a single node (to concatenate them) and then pushing the data back up to HDFS as a single file. This is even before you then get to process the file again in a mapper (or more depending on splittability of your input format split / compression codec).

If you were going to process this concatenated file multiple times, and each file is smaller than the block size, then merging them to a single file may be beneficial, but you've already noted that each file is larger than the default block size.

Is there particular reason you want all files to flow through a single mapper (which is what it sounds like is you are trying to achieve by doing these two options).